# persistent data storage in python

Tags: database, python-3.6, shelve

In my application, I need tostore/save data to the disk, so I can use it when the application runs again, like user settings.

Currently, I am using Shelve, but getting an issue with it:

The file can be created by Linux, not working in windows, also issue with the different versions of python.

I don't want to use any sql database.

Are there any other easy ways to store/save data?

Comment: You can use pickle in python to save data on disc and use later whenever required.

Comment: Thanks @Shailendra, I will check pickle